# How save e-mail on Mac, while deleting on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I need to delete email after reading them on my iPhone, but do not want to delete them on my Mac, so I can file the emails later.

How to do this?

Comment: If you're using IMAP email (most email these days is IMAP based) then you won't able to directly.  The reason is IMAP email is server based, and it's in fact doing what it's supposed to, staying synched.   That said, I did set someones iPhone up with a unique email address and used a filter to forward a copy of every inbound email to that address, just so it could work as you are suggesting.

Comment: A suggestion: just have an intermediate folder called "to be filed".  When you're done with the email in the phone move it into "to be filed", then you can actually put it where it belongs when you review on your mac later.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure iPhone email account using POP3, and Mac email account using IMAP.

In this way you're able to delete email on the phone and preserve them on Mac.